# How to pass a keyword from URL but keep it hidden? (Adwords)

Tags: php, url, get, google-ads-api

I'd essentially like to know the keyword that takes a user to my site, but then hide it from the user. So...in my ads I could set up the URL as domain.com?keyword=KW, and then store the keyword in a PHP variable so that I can use it in emails/SMS messages to myself. I don't really want it shown in the URL though as it looks kind of messy.

Is there any way to actually achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a redirect after the user gets to your site:

```
if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){
   //do whatever function you need to do with the keyword data
   $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
   //redirect
   header("Location: /");
}
```

Obviously the location should be where you want to send the user.
The "/" will put him at the page/root of where he was.

Comment: It's imperative that my site loads quickly, will the redirect not increase the load time? I still think it's probably the only and best solution.

Comment: Its really really fast, the rest of the page doesn't even load, so put the redirect at the top of your file. I would argue that there is no delay at all.

Comment: Realistically you host this as a service before your actual site, that way you can track users, drop cookies etc.